# Tap, Pan for a map & fixed headers - event conflict

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm currently developing a small WebApp that makes use of

- Google Maps (front-end uses jquery-ui-maps)
- jQuery Mobile with [a fixed header & footer](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

Now I encountered a conflict that appears on touch enabled devices as well as on desktop/mouse controlled "click" events: When I ["tap"](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) or ["click"](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html) the map to actually "pan" it, then my header/footer toggles it's visibility. As I want to keep the toggle behaviour, I can't simply deactivate it, but showing/hiding the header/footer on every "pan" of the map is odd. After thinking some time about it, I think I got a concept that should work:

**Question:** How I can I add a delay to the visibility toggle for the header/footer? So when I don't release the finger/mouse after XYms, the header/footer doesn't show/hide?

Example:

```
jQuery( '#map_page' ).live( 
    "pageinit"
    ,function() 
    {
        // Att.: pseudo code
        if ( $.mobile.taphold )
            don't toggle fixed
        if ( mousedown > XYms )
            don't toggle fixed
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery mobile: Disable "tap to toggle" fixed header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232415/jquery-mobile-disable-tap-to-toggle-fixed-header-and-footer)

Here's the solution.

JQM 1.0:

```
$(function(){
  $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
});
```

JQM 1.1:add property `data-position="fixed"` to header/footer.